# How can one add other phone skins to the Android Studio image capture tool?

Tags: android, android-studio, skin

The  "Capture image from device" that is integrated into Android Studio is super handy. (See "Source Button" in image) That there is also a built in method of framing your image for use on the Google Play store is even better. BUT... the list of phones available is pretty boring. Is there any way to add more skins to this list?

Note that this is a *different* issue than having other skins in available in the built-in XML layout tool. You can add to that list by adding directories within android-sdk/platforms/android-23/skins. I've done that, but it has no effect on the list available in the "capture-skinner".

[image: Android Studio IDE Screen Capture]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure android studio or sdk providing the customized frames but yes i am using this online tool to change the screenshots images frame.

may be this can help you in other ways

[Add Frame to the screenshot of image](http://www.appdemostore.com/frameapp)

This tools contains lots of different devices frames generally we find for our requirements